# Will a 3-phase variable frequency drive have any effect on voltage differences between phases?

Tags: voltage, three-phase, vfd

The national power provider here is not great.  There is often a 10 - 30 V difference between phases.

Will the voltage exiting a 3-phase variable frequency drive be the same as the input voltage, or does the magic voodoo in there have any balancing effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the input side of a VFD is a rectifier, which will maintain a relatively steady DC voltage on a DC link bus. On the output side of a VFD is some type of inverter that will draw from the DC link bus and feed the variable frequency voltage & current to the motor being driven. Because the output is decoupled from the input by the DC link bus, the voltage level and phase-to-phase imbalances on the input will not affect the output voltage.

Here is [a reference](http://www.vfds.org/what-is-vfd-how-it-works-964803.html) for how a VFD works.